# Why i can't upload pictures to my pasted events from my own iOS app?

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, image, facebook-ios-sdk

i came across a strange problem, when i add pictures to an past event from web-end,everything is ok,however when i did that from my own iOS app, there's no exception,i just can't see the newly added image.Can't we add photos to the past events from mobile client? Anyone knows that.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image,@"source", nil];
[facebookDelegate requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",self.eventID] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

There's no errors,but i just can't see the uploaded pictures.

And another question, how to set event's profile picture with graph api? I used the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:image,@"picture", nil];
[facebookDelegate requestWithGraphPath:self.eventID andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

It also doesn't work.What's more, i want to konw if we can upload image from web,so we just offer the picture link to facebook ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try the first one now. It work now